# Can repeated game sustain a discounted average payoff that is not individually rational?

Tags: game-theory

Look at the following payoff matrix, there are two stage Nash equlibria, and we consider a infinitely repeated game with discount factor $\delta\in(0,1)$, can players sustain an average payoff of (2,2) under any strategy? (I am confused because the individually rational(i.e. minmax) payoff is (3,3)) If not, why?

[image]

Comment: How is the mimax payoff (3,3)? The minimum for H is 0. The minimum for L is 3. Which means that if both player play minimax, they both choose L, and the payoff is (5,5).

Comment: @Acccumulation: In the repeated games literature, it's customary to define the set of individually rational payoffs as $\{(u_1,\dots,u_n): u_i\ge\min_{a_{-i}}\max_{a_i}u_i(a_i,a_{-i})\,\forall i\}$. In this case, $(3,3)$ is the minimum of this set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the result you are looking for is Lemma 2 (p.7) of these [lecture notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz9XuTKbxavEZGY3ODE4MGMtYmJhZi00NGM4LTkwZDYtZWU3NzU0ZWEyMWFi/view) by Johannes Hörner. Also see the papers he references in the end.
There is a formal proof, but the idea is exactly what Herr K. wrote in his post.
In your repeated game, all players must have an average payoff of at least 3 in Nash equilibrium.

Comment: Wonderful! thanks! Just wondering how to convert this "obvious" idea into a formal proof.

Answer (score 3):

I'm inclined to say $(2,2)$ is not sustainable, though I don't have a formal proof at the moment.

To achieve an average payoff of $(2,2)$, the players must play $(H,H)$ in some stages. But then a player can deviate to playing $L$ and avoid any subsequent punishments by ensuring that he can always get at least $3$, which is better than $2$.